# dynamodb AND condition in Filter expression

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

dynamodb Table

**Schema**:

```
id, email, dateOfBirth, subscriptionEndDate
```

I want to get the list of  1. attribute_not_exist(dateOfBirth) 2. subscriptionEndDate is in future.

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

```
const params = {
            TableName: 'Users',
            ProjectionExpression: "id, dateOfBirth, subscriptionEndDate",
            FilterExpression: "attribute_not_exists(dateOfBirth)",                
        };
docClient.scan(params).promise();
```

When I try to add AND condition in `FilterExpression: "attribute_not_exists(dateOfBirth),`

Error: `"Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error"`

```
id - partition key
subscriptionEndDate - sort key
```

Any suggestions

Comment: The FilterExpression string never ends... Isn't that the syntax error?

Comment: @NadavHar'El updated

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue:

```
    const currentDate = '2021-07-31'
    const params = {
                TableName:'Users',
                ProjectionExpression: "id, dateOfBirth,subscriptionEndDate",
                FilterExpression: "attribute_not_exists(dateOfBirth) and #subscriptionEndDate > :today",
                ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                    "#subscriptionEndDate": "subscriptionEndDate"
                },
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ":today": currentDate
                }
            };


docClient.scan(params).promise();
```

Comment: Scan is an inefficient approach. Scan will go through the whole data and do the filtration. I suggest you to create an LSI at table creation time with user id as  PartitionKey and subscriptionEndDate as Sortkey then you can use that LSI for directly query the data instead of using Scan. If table already exits, then you can check GSI.